# iOS 7 app background allowed activities

Tags: ios7, core-location, iphone-5, reachability, core-telephony

I am working on an app which will capture location updates, network reachability, Telephony details. I have registered my app for Background Modes - Location updates and Background Fetch.

OS Version - iOS 7.1

I have few queries on what I can do in background mode..

(1) As my app is registered for location updates in Background mode, Can I monitor Network reachability, Call Status, Battery Level ? I have googled much but not exactly clear whether it is allowed to monitor and capture network data, Battery data and call data when my app is registered for location updates when running in background.

(2) Is it allowed to run secondary thread while app is in background state ?

(3) Purpose of capturing the said data is to save the captured data in sqlite database and send to a server using web services. Is it allowed ?

My app will go to Apple app store hence I am looking for acceptable approach.

Somewhere I read that if your app registered for VOIP in background modes then you can create a socket and can capture the data. But I am not sure if this way works or can be acceptable by Apple App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do all the thing that you intend to do (as you have stated) as long as you DO NOT make any call to OpenGL ES.

> iOS prevents background apps from accessing the graphics processor so that the frontmost app is always able to present a great experience to the user. Your app can be terminated not only if it makes OpenGL ES calls while in the background but also if previously submitted commands are flushed to the GPU while in the background. Your app must ensure that all previously submitted commands have finished executing before moving into the background.

---

Apple provides a good guide about what to do and not to do when in background here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

See the **Being a Responsible Background App** section.

Comment: Thanks Anindya for taking sometime to provide me an answer.. But as per apple guidelines in the same link it says, when an iOS app in background mode, it can only perform tasks related to 'Location Data', 'Background Fetch', 'VOIP', Audio, Bluetooth etc.. But it doesn't tell that "while registered for one of the approved services like 'Location Data' is it possible to use other services like reachability, Call Status, Battery Level.." So if you have faced any such use case please help me to understand.. Many Thanks again..

Comment: It is possible and Apple approves it. Apple leaves the task of detecting illegal actions to iOS itself. The main concern Apple has is   that the foreground app should be allocated maximum resources. That is the reason of all these restrictions. As long as you are allowing that  (by not doing heavy stuff like calling OpenGL or consuming high memory) Apple is okay with you.